# Javascript is not displaying correct cells from excel

Tags: javascript, excel

```
<script language="javascript" >
function GetData(cell,row){
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("http://kb.healthnet.com/al/12/2/72550.xls");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("CA 2012-2013 HMO Plans");
var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
var data2 = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
document.getElementById('div1').innerText = data;
document.getElementById('div2').innerText = data2;
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Hearing Services" onClick="GetData(45,2);(46,2);" />
</td>
<td>
<div id="div1" style="background: #e2e2e2; width:'100%';" align="center">45,2 will display here</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<div id="div2" style="background: #e2e2e2; width:'100%';" align="center">46,2 will display here</div>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

See, in both 45,2 and 46,2 td's only 45,2 is displayed on both td's. I've tried changing just about everything so I think I'm lacking the function logic of how its structured. I've been trying to skim through books because this thing project is time sensitive so its hard to focus.

Comment: Based on your update my answer still holds: you're overwriting the contents of the divs on the second call to `GetData()`. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

What is `GetData(45,2)&(46,2)`?

If you are trying to do two separate function calls, it should be `GetData(45,2)` and again `GetData(46,2)`. But you're using a strange operator, `&`--did you mean to concatenate the values? If so, you're using VB operators in Javascript.

To address your display problem, what do you want to accomplish? Provide an example of the data that is in the cells, and what you want the divs to contain after their content is updated. Then we can possibly help you more.

Additionally, it is not considered best practice to put your functions as text inside the `onclick` attribute. In general it's better to create an actual function, and upon page load, attach it:

```
function hearingServicesClick() {
   GetData(45, 2);
   GetData(46, 2);
}

document.getElementById('hearingservices').onclick = hearingServicesClick;
```

Comment: The data in the cells hold words and number such as Benefit copay $5 and the other the fine print. its displaying only one of the cells. I've tried the GetData (45,2);GetData(46,2); on the onclick event h. but again it only gave me one cells info. basically, Im trying to use a link to pull info from an excel file cells (2) and display them in table data I designated with the div. But you said to create another function to handle the two different cells? Did I understand you right? (thanks for your input by the way!)

Comment: Your `GetData` function completely overwrites the contents of the `div`s each time. You are not appending to the divs! So of course, the final successful call is the only one you will see. If you want to display data in a table, then you need to construct a table--I don't see any `<table><tr><td>` type elements here... ?

Comment: its there. I just didn't display it. The table is large with multiple links. I cant build a function for each link. there are at least 20 links that I need to use to pull info from different cells. The div's are in different td's in different tr's. that part is fine. I just don't get why they are displaying the same info. let me see what I can show you.

Comment: document.getElementById('div1').innerText = data;
  document.getElementById('div2').innerText = data2;
}
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="div1" style="background: #e2e2e2; width:'100%';" >Blah</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" onClick="GetData(27,3); GetData(28,3);">benefit</a></td>
<td><div id="div2"></div></td>

Comment: damn, not what I expected. I guess I'm just stuck. Hey, thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I dont wanna take more of your time when you could be helping others. I'll figure something out.

Comment: If you post MORE DETAILS in your question, then we might be able to help you. As it is, by not posting at least enough content to help us understand the true problem, well, let's say we haven't gotten very far, and that's not a very good use of time! I'd prefer that you just provide the needed detail. Based on your question, you are replacing the entire content of the `div`s each time. How could I have given you a better answer with that kind of wrong information?

Comment: @ErikE: If you don't have enough information to answer the question, then you should have clarified the point with a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: no no, I know I'm not giving you right info. This is something new to me and I'm doing this for my company so its hard to give more info without losing my job. I'm normally a VB coder but haven't stuck my hand in Javascript. Let me see if I can reedit what I posted with more details. give me five minutes.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Woulda coulda shoulda... :) user1739280: please put your updated code in your question, not here in  comments.